# Table Data Import Wizard 'Could not determine delimiter'

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to import into my database a csv file using Table Data Import Wizard tool, to a table that just has one attribute (it's id VARCHAR(10)), the import is failing showing me this error: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lb5jP.png)
I've checked the csv file in order to find any wierd characters or newline characters but everything is fine. Im using version 8.0.25 and the logs are showing this:

```
16:00:09 [ERR][       pymforms]: Unhandled exception in Python code: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\workbench\wizard_page_widget.py", line 97, in go_next
    self.main.go_next_page()
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\workbench\wizard_form.py", line 76, in go_next_page
    self.pages[index].page_activated(True)
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\sqlide_power_import_wizard.py", line 185, in page_activated
    self.call_create_preview_table()
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\sqlide_power_import_wizard.py", line 343, in call_create_preview_table
    self.create_preview_table(self.call_analyze())
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\sqlide_power_import_wizard.py", line 352, in call_analyze
    if not self.active_module.analyze_file():
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\sqlide_power_import_export_be.py", line 511, in analyze_file
    self.dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvsample)
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\Python\Lib\csv.py", line 188, in sniff
    raise Error("Could not determine delimiter")
_csv.Error: Could not determine delimiter
```

And here is how my csv file looks:

```
id_tren
56X0O
12X0Y
91X0F
13X0P
92X0U
```

Comment: can you add two or three lines of your csv, maybe it is a bug in workbench, that should be reported, Which Version are you using

Comment: sure no problem, adding it to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A csv are Comma-separated values.

so you have to give  the importer some commas

like

```
id_tren,
56X0O,
12X0Y,
91X0F,
13X0P,
92X0U,
```

then you get

[image: table data import workbench mysql]

and select the column you want

Comment: oh so it always needs 2 columns? in the other cvs files i have with more than one column the last wouldnt have any coma so i just followed that rule for making this csv

Comment: no if you have more than one column you don't need to add more, only in cqase you have only one column, that the importer can't handle, iy you need to configure the import click on the spanner behind detected file format csv